# Maybe We should classify questions on SO using other tags?

Tags: discussion

Maybe SO should allow the users to add their own tags to a question.

For example, Users can tag a question as `Elementary` which means it is for elementay level users, or tag it as `Obscure` which means it is difficult to understand.

Many people dont seem to understand my intention. You cant tag your own question as `Elementary`, other people tag it.

Comment: Maybe? Okay, why? What advantage do you see in this approach?

Comment: The advantage is that people could browse the questions insted of just search them.

Comment: Even if *other* people are tagging the question, who's to say that my idea of elementary is the same as anyone else's?

Answer (score 7):

Those are [meta tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), which we've avoided for several years now.

> The reason meta-tags are a problem is that they do not describe the content of the question. They describe some other aspect of the question, like the author’s skill level, or the author’s motivation for asking it, or generally what “kind” of question it is (poll, how-to, etc.).
>
> Meta-tags are actually a subset of a larger problem that I usually call dependent tags. These are tags that don’t say anything by themselves – you can’t tell what the question is about unless they’re paired with some other tag (or several of them). These tags are a problem because people don’t realize this and will often use that as the question’s only tag.

Tagging by difficulty is especially problematic. Who judges the level of difficulty? What if I want to tag my question as obscure but an expert wants to tag it elementary?

Comment: You dont tag your own questions using `meta tags`, other people tag it. If many people tag your questions as `obscure`, you should consider improving the clarity.

Comment: @JamesKing We already have a mechanism for marking questions unclear: upvotes and downvotes.

Comment: And closing as "Unclear what you're asking".